# How to include images in a CSHTML page from an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

All the  links in my CSHTML page within my ASP.NET Core API IIS extension show as broken, even though I have `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

A simple example is a *Welcome.cshtml* page with this content:

```
@page
@model MyAPI.Pages.WelcomeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <img src="~/ImageX.png" />
    <p>My Web API</p>
</div>
```

and a *Welcome.cshtml.cs* page containing this:

```
namespace MyAPI.Pages
{
    public class WelcomeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WelcomeModel> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public WelcomeModel(ILogger<WelcomeModel> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me this result:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: And `ImageX.png` exists in your wwwroot folder? What can you see for the network request in your browser development tools?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman. Well. No. The image doesn't exist in my wwwroot folder as I have not published the project yet, and port 7061 doesn't exist in my IIS either. This is running from within the IDE. Does that mean it is not possible?

Comment: To piggyback off the comment above, you need to ensure that the context of where your app expects that file to be after deployment may differ from when you are running locally. The app could be looking for the file you referenced in the root, but it does not exist or is located elsewhere when running during this scenario.

Comment: @workinMan So it's not possible to see static image files when running the API from within Visual Studio, but they may well work once it's published to IIS?

Comment: In a debug build, the `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` should be your project folder. `UseStaticFiles` will then default to `~/wwwroot`. Obviously when you publish this folder would be copied.

Comment: @SiBrit, I think that you provided some more context that is helpful. If you're running locally, I believe locating the resource in the artifacts directory created when you build your code is still the issue. You have an application looking for" imageX.png" within its specific context: 

App: "Where do I find this file to show that's referenced here?: <img src="~/ImageX.png" />"

To the renderer (aka your application), it seemingly can't find this file. Where should your code look for this when it is running?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeremy's comment, I added a wwwroot sub-folder to my project folder, and moved the images into that. They now appear when I run the project within the IDE and they are put into the *C:\Inetpub\wwwroot* folder on publishing.

Note that the wwwroot folder gets a special icon within the Solution Explorer.

[image]